# Are microbes that don't make you sick able to reproduce more numerously or at a faster rate in the human body than microbes that do make you sick?

Tags: infection, bacteria, virus

Are microbes that don't make you sick able to reproduce more numerously or at a faster rate in the human body than microbes that do make you sick? I wouldn't want to assume much on this question.

Comment: It's a very wide question. there are diseases provoked by microbes in the stomach, other diseases provoked by microbes on the skin, in the intestine, etc.. it's so wide that it's really difficult to answer.